# Tkinter erratic handling of mouse events

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm trying to simulate a cursor by drawing it on a canvas and moving it in response to motion events.

According to the documentation *"there is no mouse event for mouse motion without pressing a button, except for Enter and Leave"*. Tkinter, however, accepts binding to a `<Motion>` event which seems to be what I want except except for one thing: you must click somewhere in the root window first for `<Motion>` to start firing. Once the pointer leaves the window, reentering without a click will trigger `<Enter>` but not `<Motion>` - even if the window never loses focus.

Such behavior is incompatible with my goal (puzzling too; why would anyone want that?) so I wrote a little program to see if I could change it, perhaps by using `event_generate`. I couldn't (yet), but in the process I found that Tkinter gets kind of fuzzy handling mouse events. For one thing, it misses `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` quite often (you move the pointer out and it still thinks it's in, and vice versa). Even more surprising: sometimes, when you move the pointer in, it fires `<Enter>`  and one or two `<Motion>` events **without clicking in the root window**. Then it goes silent: no more `<Motion>` events until you click. You can reproduce these problems with the code below. I'm running OS X El Capitan, Python 2.7.

Any explanations of these behaviors, or ideas on how to track motion events without clicking will be appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *

def enter(e):
    if e.widget is not canvas:
        print "<Enter> caught by", e.widget
    if canvas.state != "outside":
        print "<Enter> in 'inside' state!"
    canvas.state = "inside"
    canvas.n = 0
    canvas.itemconfig(inout, text=canvas.state)
    canvas.itemconfig(count, text="no motions yet")
    canvas.event_generate('<Button-1>', x=e.x, y=e.y, state=0x0100)
    #canvas.update()

def motion(e):
    if canvas.state == "outside":
        print "<Motion> in 'outside' state!"
    canvas.n += 1
    canvas.itemconfig(count, text="motions since enter: {:03d}".format(canvas.n))
    #canvas.update()

def leave(e):
    if e.widget is not canvas:
        print "Leave caught by", e.widget
    if canvas.state == "outside":
        print "<Leave> in 'outside' state!"
    canvas.state = "outside"
    canvas.itemconfig(inout, text=canvas.state)
    canvas.itemconfig(count, text="")
    #canvas.update()

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='#E4E4E4', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
canvas.create_text(140, 20, text="(tracking <Enter>, <Motion>, <Leave>)")
inout = canvas.create_text(140, 100, text="outside")
count = canvas.create_text(140, 120, text="")

canvas.n = 0
canvas.state = "outside"

canvas.bind('<Enter>', enter)
canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)
canvas.bind('<Leave>', leave)

canvas2 = Canvas(frame, height=100, highlightthickness=0)
canvas2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
canvas2.create_text(140, 50, text="(no tracking here)")
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

def focusout(e):
    print "root lost focus"

root.bind('<FocusOut>', focusout)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"According to the documentation"_ - which documentation? That documentation is wrong.

Comment: Some O'Reilly book... http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-16-sect-9.html

Comment: So, that's where I got that quotation from. Any idea about why I get <Motion> events occasionally? Or about tracking <Motion>s after <Leave>, <Enter>?

Comment: On Windows your  example seems to work as expected. I have been <Motion> tracking for years without issues.